# Android SIP Audio Call Reject SDP: no suitable codecs

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sip

What is Reject SDP: no suitable codecs?

This error has occurred while **accepting** incoming **SIP** audio call.
It's working fine If I call between my same two apps but not in between my app and other already developed apps.

my same apps provide:

```
v=0
o=- 1552476987912 1552476987915 IN IP4 91.121.209.194
s=-
c=IN IP4 91.121.209.194
t=0 0
a=nortpproxy:yes
m=audio 49896 RTP/AVP 96 97 3 0 8 127
a=rtpmap:96 GSM-EFR/8000
a=rtpmap:97 AMR/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:127 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:127 0-15
```

others apps provide:

```
v=0
o=nks2_7 3358 1070 IN IP4 54.37.202.229
s=Talk
c=IN IP4 54.37.202.229
t=0 0
a=ice-pwd:93b332893d9688f0426a432d
a=ice-ufrag:6a48740a
a=rtcp-xr:rcvr-rtt=all:10000 stat-summary=loss,dup,jitt,TTL voip-    metrics
a=nortpproxy:yes
m=audio 57322 RTP/AVPF 96 97 98 0 8 18 101 99 100
c=IN IP4 54.37.202.229
a=rtpmap:96 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:96 useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:97 speex/16000
a=fmtp:97 vbr=on
a=rtpmap:98 speex/8000
a=fmtp:98 vbr=on
a=fmtp:18 annexb=yes
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:99 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:100 telephone-event/8000
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2130706303 192.168.1.7 7076 typ host
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2130706302 192.168.1.7 7077 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 1694498687 202.166.217.114 7076 typ srflx raddr                         192.168.1.7 rport 7076
a=candidate:2 2 UDP 1694498686 202.166.217.114 7077 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.7 rport 7077
a=rtcp-fb:* trr-int 1000
a=rtcp-fb:* ccm tmmbr
a=candidate:66e88eef705b5c6c 1 UDP 16777215 54.37.202.229 57322 typ relay raddr 202.166.217.114 rport 7076
a=candidate:66e88eef705b5c6c 2 UDP 16777214 54.37.202.229 57323 typ relay raddr 202.166.217.114 rport 7077
a=nortpproxy:yes
```

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: It might be the codecs supplied in the SDP offer/answer don't match with the codecs supported by the app. Please provide the SDP offer and answer and a list of codecs the app supports.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But do we need to provide modified codecs?.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with modified codecs. Each party should specify in the SDP body it sends a list of codecs it supports. The list in the SDP answer must be a subset of the list in the SDP offer. See RFC 4317 for some examples. If you provide your SDP offer and answer in the description other people can help you find any problems.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a single codec in common between your app and the other app you are trying to connect.

Codecs on your app: GSM-EFR  AMR, GSM, PCMU, PCMA

Codecs on the other app: opus, speex (wide and narrowband), G729

Your app has to have ate least one of the other apps' codecs

Comment: It only gives issue while calling from Linphone app, it's might be due to some extra settings included on Linphone app.
But on except Linphone app, other apps from play store working fine.

Comment: According to Linphone's site: https://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone they support PCMA and PCMU (g711), so it should be possible to enable those codecs so that it would become compatible with your app